# Open Microsoft Word Document in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to open a Word Document in Excel in order to dump a bunch of info into it. I'm using the following code:

```
   'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object and create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box
    Dim iFileSelect As FileDialog
    Set iFileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Declare a variable to contain the path of each selected item
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box
    'The user pressed the action button
     If iFileSelect.Show = -1 Then

     For Each vrtSelectedItem In iFileSelect.SelectedItems
     'vrtSelectedItem contains  path of each selected item
     MsgBox "The path is: " & vrtSelectedItem
     Next vrtSelectedItem

     End If

    'Set object variable to Nothing
    Set iFileSelect = Nothing
```

I"m having the following issues:

1. I have no idea if the document actually opened or not.
2. How do I close and save the file once I have dumped info into it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a workbook open in Excel, you can just use its FollowHyperlink method to open the document.

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim iFileSelect As FileDialog
    Set iFileSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    If iFileSelect.Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In iFileSelect.SelectedItems
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink vrtSelectedItem
        Next vrtSelectedItem
    End If

    Set iFileSelect = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool. But how will you edit and save the same from VBA? send keys...... just kidding :)